# Javascript Hours of Operation check date and time with getTimezoneOffset

Tags: javascript, if-statement, time, timezone

**Updated**: See below original post.

**Start original post**
Working on changing my client's chat button to an "offline mode" if a user visits the site outside the chat hours of operation.

Hours of operation are 9am-5pm Eastern Time (American, not Australian) Monday through Friday. When I say Eastern Time, it does need to take into account for Winter/Summer months for EST/EDT.

EST is UTC - 5 during winter months (1st Sunday in November until 2nd Sunday in March)
EDT is UTC - 4 during summer months (2nd Sunday in March until 1st Sunday in November)

To avoid problems (visitor might not have computer time set correctly) I opted to use `getUTCDay()` and `getUTCHours()` instead of `getDay()` and `getHours()`.

To convert the UTC time into EST/EDT, I subtracted `getTimezoneOffset()` from `getUTCHours()` (dividing `getTimezoneOffset()` by 60 to get hours instead of minutes first). The reason I went with this method is because according to the [Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) `getTimezoneOffset()` is not a constant and takes into account Daylight Saving Time.

All seems well (I think) until the if statements (which is where I believe I went wrong)
Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TLJsv/
**Javascript**

```
function chatOffline() {
    var d = new Date();
    var currentMonth = d.getUTCMonth();
    var currentDay = d.getUTCDay();
    var currentHours = d.getUTCHours();
    var currentMinutes = d.getUTCMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = d.getUTCSeconds();
    var offSet = d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    var offMode = function offMode() {
        jQuery('.initChat').css('background-position', '-68px 0px'); //switches sprite to offline position
        jQuery('.initChat').css('cursor', 'context-menu'); //changes cursor so button appears to be not clickable
    };
    //set UTC time to either EST or EDT
    currentHours -= offSet;

    //check if day is between Mon-Fri
    if (currentDay < 1) {
        offMode(); // It's Sunday
    } else if (currentDay > 5) {
        offMode(); // It's Saturday
    } else {
        //check if time is earlier than 9am 
        if (currentHours < 9) {
            offMode(); // It's before 9am ET
        } else if
        //check if time is later than 5pm
        (currentHours > 17) {
            offMode(); // It's after 5pm ET
        } else if
        //check if it is 5pm
        (currentHours == 17) {
            //if it's past 5pm, even by a second, go offline
            if (currentSeconds > 0) {
                offMode(); // It's after 5pm ET
            }
        }
    }
}
chatOffline();
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TLJsv/

During testing I changed the numbers in lines 23, 27, and 31 (currently the number 9 and number 17) to different values to confirm the chat link goes to offline mode. It doesn't work every time. I think the problem is with the if statement on line 23 (which checks if time is earlier than 9am). The next two seem to work fine.

Any help or improvements on this would be greatly appreciated!

**End original post**

**Update**
I realized I had my last 2 `else if`s in wrong order, I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TLJsv/3/

Comment: Do you have to do this in client-side JavaScript?  What happens if the customer's clock (not just the TZ) is set wrong?  The best solution would be for the server to use its own clock and report back a true/false value for whether chat is available or not.  In most server-side programming languages, you have time zone functions available so you don't need to figure out the DST rule yourself.

Comment: Hi Matt, wouldn't getUTCHours prevent that from happening? If I correctly understood the difference between getHours vs getUTCHours.

Comment: No.  Both still use the clock of the user's computer.  It just returns the value relative to UTC rather than to the user's local time zone.

Comment: Also, you can't just subtract the offset from the hours component.  The day, month and year may also change.  The UTC day is not necessarily the same as the local day.  Not everyone's "today" is the same at any given instant.  Besides, if you care about US Eastern Time, you don't really need to know the user's own local offset at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the user's clock to come into play, you'll have to do this on the server.  There's no magic in `getUTCHours` that reaches out to a server for the time.  It still uses the time in the `Date` object, which is obtained from the user's clock.

However, if you don't care about that, then the easiest way to do this in client-side JavaScript would be to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on.

```
var m = moment().tz("America/New_York");  // US Eastern Time Zone

if (m.day() < 1 || m.day() > 5 || m.hour() < 9 || m.hour() >= 17) {
    offMode();
}
```

Note also that when it comes to ranges that include a time, humans usually mean this to be a half-open interval (ie. 9AM-5PM includes 9AM, but excludes 5PM).  When ranges don't include a time, then humans usually mean it to be a fully inclusive interval (ie. Mon-Fri is 5 days, not 4).

Comment: Is there a way to use moment.js and moment-timezone add-on in jsfiddle via external resource? Just so I can test? Been trying the CDN links at http://cdnjs.com/ but I can't get it to work with the code you provided. Suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working, apparently dropbox doesn't work for external resources in jsfiddle, thanks for the great answer Matt! :)

Comment: Here's a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ESq7M/  Don't forget [the data](http://momentjs.com/timezone/data/) for the time zone you're interested in! :)